# Online Sangha groups

Tags: sangha

What Internet-based Sangha groups are out there?

For the Plum Village tradition there is a list on [plumline.org](http://plumline.org/)

Are there any other lists of online Sanghas you can share?

Grateful for help and with kind regards,
Tord

Answer (score 4):

There is a Theravada group which is run by monastics at [Bhavana Society](http://bhavanasociety.org/). They run the group through Discord, they do group meditations, sutta readings and book study sessions. You can join their Discord server [here](https://discord.gg/utz8TkU)

There is also an online meditation group who use google hangouts. They usually do meditations twice every weekday. They aren't affiliated with any Buddhist tradition although there is a monastic who hosts meditations regularly. This is their [google plus page](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+RedditationOnline)

Answer (score 0):

Venerable members of the Sangha, Ven. Fellows, valued Buddha-Parisata, Householder Tord, interested,

asked about Sangha online, (Buddha-[Parisa](http://accesstoinsight.eu/en/dictionary/parisa) would denote mixed or lay-assemblings), there is a tiny online monastery, dedicated for the Sangha of the eight directions and devoted follower and also open for all interested: [Virtual Dhamma Vinaya Vihara](http://sangham.net/index.php?action=forum), with all possibilities for practicing and "socializing" with the Tripple Gems, lesser common the many Buddhist-Social-places. ([objectives](http://sangham.net/index.php/topic,8.0.html), development and online since some 6 years, surely not most modern and up-to-date technics, 100% trade-free and nearly free of use of third part recources, not public areas, proper for each kind of relationship).

There are surely planty of merely privat and mostly lay communities, but since having seen that there is another question in regard of sozial-networks, thought to not start to list much here.

Some Venerables individually run there own groups.

"Physical" Monasteries mostly run such as email-groups if even, or present them via fb or similar.

My person is not aware of any similar, aside of the mentioned Australian. There are some "closed up" in German languages.

Looking forward that such get in given form and proper run more frequently so that many may have possibilities to often meet monks, the Sangha of the Buddha and be able to practice even when no physical near.